# html text to select a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, search, text, input

So I am quite a noob to this whole coding thing, and after having done some training and getting to know JavaScript, Html and CSS I have set myself a challenge. This is to make a Batcomputer/Jarvis to manage my google agenda, games, program's and more. But for this I need to search a html text input for words to then start appropriate function's.

Here are the parts of code that matter:

```
<input type="text" id="inputField" onchange="insertInput()"></input>

<script>
var currentInput = 1;
//The input and function picker
function insertInput() {
  document.getElementById("inputHtml").innerHTML = currentInput;
  console.log(currentInput);
  var containsLaunchGame = /launch game/g;
  var resultLaunchGame = currentInput.test(containsLaunchGame);
  console.log(resultLaunchGame);

  if (resultLaunchGame = true) {
    scanGames();
    console.log("I found Launch Game");
  };
};
</script>
```

This isn't all of the code but just the parts I have questions about.
Other than just string.test I have also tried string.search and a few others, but none work how I want them to.

What I am going for (doesn't really matter how) is that I can tell my pc to do something based on what I type. But all of the ways I have tried result in an error.

For the code above the error is "Uncaught TypeError: currentInput.test is not a function".

If you have any way of fixing this, no matter how, then I would appreciate that a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few syntax errors in your code. Please see the inline comments for fixes. You should take a look at your browser console. With Chrome dev tools we have very powerful debugging tools at our disposal.

```js
var currentInput = 1;

function insertInput() {
  // assigning current input was backwards, and you should use `value` for inputs
  currentInput = document.getElementById("inputField").value;
  console.log(currentInput);
  var containsLaunchGame = /launch game/g;
  // the regex test is also backwards. test is a method on a regex not a string
  var resultLaunchGame = containsLaunchGame.test(currentInput);
  console.log(resultLaunchGame);
  // in the if statement you were using a single equals, which is the
  // assignment operator, == or === test for equality
  if (resultLaunchGame === true) {
    // scanGames();
    console.log("I found Launch Game");
  };
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputField" onchange="insertInput()" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are calling with the "currentInput.test(containsLaunchGame);" part is actually  var currentInput = 1; => 1.test()

Replace this line:

```
document.getElementById("inputHtml").innerHTML = currentInput;
```

with:

```
currentInput = document.getElementById("inputHtml").innerHTML;
```

After that replace

```
var resultLaunchGame = currentInput.string.indexOf(containsLaunchGame) !== -1;
console.log(resultLaunchGame);

if (resultLaunchGame = true) {
```

with

```
var resultLaunchGame = currentInput.test(containsLaunchGame);
console.log(resultLaunchGame);

if (resultLaunchGame == true) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The test method belongs to a RegExp object and accepts the string to be tested as param ...

try:

```
containsLaunchGame.test(currentInput);
```

Answer (score 0):

`.test` is not a function of `string`, but [`Regexp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) instead.

So use

```
var resultLaunchGame = containsLaunchGame.test(currentInput);
```

Also, your console log shows `"I found Launch Game"` with upper case, and your regex `/launch game/g` is not accounting for it. If you want to be case insensitive, use `/launch game/gi` instead.

Answer (score 0):

currentInput is a number and not a string so you can't use string methods like `.search`

Try making currentInput a string and use the .search method

also, your example did not include the element with id "inputHtml".

instead of `onchange` try using `oninput` as `onchange` does not appear to fire everytime a key is pressed, only on blur

Example 1 adding a innerHtml element

```js
    var currentInput = '1';
    //The input and function picker
    document.getElementById('inputField').oninput = insertInput;

    function insertInput() {
      document.getElementById("inputHtml").innerHTML = currentInput;
      console.log(currentInput);
      var containsLaunchGame = /launch game/g;
      var resultLaunchGame = currentInput.search(containsLaunchGame);
      console.log(resultLaunchGame);

      if (resultLaunchGame === 0) {
      //scanGames();
      console.log("I found Launch Game");
      }
    }
```

```html
    <div id="inputHtml">
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="inputField" />
```

Example 2 assuming you wanted to use `document.getElementById("inputText")` instead of `document.getElementById("inputHtml")`

```js
    //The input and function picker
    document.getElementById('inputField').oninput = insertInput;

    function insertInput() {
      currentInput = document.getElementById("inputField").value
      console.log(currentInput);
      var containsLaunchGame = /launch game/g;
      var resultLaunchGame = currentInput.search(containsLaunchGame);
      console.log(resultLaunchGame);

      if (resultLaunchGame === 0) {
      //scanGames();
      console.log("I found Launch Game");
      }
    }
```

```html
    <input type="text" id="inputField" />
```